# Calling method to print int

Tags: java, arrays, methods, 2d

I'm just about finished with a program for finding the smallest int in a 2d array and then returning it. I want to return the smallest int and then print it in main though. I just cant figure out how to call the findSmallest method so I can print it in main. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public class FinalQ1 {

    public int[][] createArray(int rSize, int cSize) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int[][] array = new int[rSize][cSize];
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < array[0].length; col++) {
                array[row][col] = r.nextInt(101);
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

    public int findSmallest(int[][] Array) {
        int[][] coord = Array;
        int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for (int i = 0; i < coord.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < coord.length; i++) {
                if (smallest > coord[i][j]) {
                    smallest = coord[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return smallest;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FinalQ1 c = new FinalQ1();
        int small;
        small = c.findSmallest();
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(small);` also, you need a `j++` in you inner for loop (not `i++`).

Comment: `findSmallest()` requires a 2d array

Comment: it looks like you'll want to use createArray to first create your 2d array.
    `System.out.println(c.findSmallest(createArray(2, 2)); `
will do everything in one shot

Comment: @ElliottFrisch oops lol didn't notice that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since `createArray()` creates a 2d array ,pass the returned array to `findSmallest()`

```
 small = c.findSmallest(createArray(3,3));
```